# SASS Image CSS Cache Busting (via Compass)

Tags: css, caching, sass, compass-sass

Can anyone explain a best practice approach to implementing a cache buster in SASS? Meaning, on 'compilation' of my CSS, it appends a timestamp to images files. E.g.,

The following SASS code:

```
!sprite="gubs.gif"

ul
  li.selected
    :background
      :image= image_url(!sprite)
      :repeat no-repeat
      :position= "right" -222px
```

Should produce:

```
ul li.selected {
  background: url(../images/gubs.gif?123456789) no-repeat right -222px
}
```

In the ruby tool juicer, this is automatically done for you. But I can't seem to find documentation on how to do this in SASS, via Compass.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are using compass v0.6.5 or greater.

Also, you'll need to make sure you have the `images_dir` set in your configuration file relative to your project root directory and set `http_images_path = :relative`.

Once you have done all that, and it's still not working, the best place to get support is the compass mailing list.

Comment: I have the latest v0.6.15, and also :relative set. There is still no cache buster appended to the image paths. I guess this is really just a missing feature in SASS? Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: It works very nicely for me in compass v0.10.5. You need to set the `images_dir` and `http_images_dir` config flags so compass can find you images. I am not using `relative_assets` but I think that works as well.