# sass cache busting

Tags: css, ruby, caching, sass

Is there a way to do file rev cache busting in SASS? It appears to be possible using compass per this answer here:
[SASS Image CSS Cache Busting (via Compass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975996/sass-image-css-cache-busting-via-compass)

but I haven't found any way to do this just using SASS.  Is there any way to have SASS get file modification info from the filesystem, and append to an image path?

And I'd prefer to not append query strings- rather, I think this is a better methodology.

Comment: it looks like this is indeed possible by defining a custom sass function: http://www.seancolombo.com/2010/07/28/how-to-make-and-use-a-custom-sass-function/  but I'm not familiar at all w/ Ruby.  I'd prefer to not have to specify the custom function via the command line, and instead continue to use the SASS watch command.

Comment: You're right about avoiding query strings - they can be ignored (http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/).  If you're using ruby and presumably rails, are you using v3? Rails asset pipeline does it all for you, if not then sprockets may be helpful.  When you put an image reference, you use image-url() rather than url() so the path is calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Dawn for chiming in after all this time!  I've since figured this out, but forgot I posted here about it.

I have a custom rb file that I reference when I run sass via the command line - like so:

```
sass --update sass:css -r file_mod.rb
```

in file_mod.rb, I have the following ruby function which does the trick:

```
require 'sass'

module GETMODINT
def file_url(staticFilePath,staticHost,filePath)
    assert_type filePath, :String
    filePath = filePath.value #get string value of literal
    staticFilePath = staticFilePath.value 
    staticHost = staticHost.value 
    modtime = File.mtime(filePath).to_i
    #Sass::Script::Number.new(modtime)

    fileBaseName = File.basename filePath, '.*'
    fileDir = File.dirname(filePath).sub(staticFilePath,'')
    fileExt = File.extname(filePath)
    path = "url('#{staticHost}#{fileDir}/#{fileBaseName}.#{modtime}#{fileExt}')"
    return Sass::Script::String.new(path)
end
Sass::Script::Functions.declare :modInt, [:filePath]
end

module Sass::Script::Functions
    include GETMODINT
end
```

Then, in a sass mixin, I simply reference the file_url function, passing it the parameters it needs to build the result:

```
@mixin backgroundImage($path, $position:0 0, $repeat:no-repeat) {
background: {
    image:file_url($staticFilePath,$staticHost,$path);
    position:$position;
    repeat:$repeat;
}   
}
```

In my case, I'm using it to construct a css background image path. Should be easily modified to suit other purposes.